# Set number of tcbtheorem

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

For the ordinary theorem environments in `LaTeX`, `amslatex`, etc., you can easily set the theorem number, for instance by temporarily setting the appropriate counters, or by redefining the functions that create the label, etc.

Do the `tcolorbox` theorem environments created with `\newtcbtheorem` have the functionality to reset the number on a theorem.

Here's a minimal example. What would I need to do to make the theorem in this document "Theorem 7.9"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}
\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know the `tcolorbox` package does not have a easy way to manipulate the counter value other than using the `code=` key with

`code={\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{8}}` where `\tcbcounter` is replaced by the real counter name of the box used.

With `number within=section`  an automatic reset of the theorem counter within sections can be achieved.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}
\section{My nice section}
\begin{Theorem}[code={\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{8}}]{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providetcbcountername}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    --undefined--%
  }{%
    tcb@cnt@#1%
  }
}

\newcommand{\settcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \setcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}%
   }%
}%

\newcommand{\displaytcbcounter}[1]{% Wrapper for \the...
  \@ifundefined{thetcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \csname thetcb@cnt@#1\endcsname% 
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}
\section{My nice section}

\settcbcounter{Theorem}{8}

The counter for theorem is \providetcbcountername{Theorem} and it has the value of \displaytcbcounter{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.      
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. That works. It appears I can't access tcbcounter from outside the environment. Is that so? If so, how does tcbtheorem achieve that?

Comment: @RMM: You can access the counter name by looking into the `.log` file -- it reveals how `tcolorbox` names the counter. If the counter is named `foo`, the `tcb` name is `tcb@cnt@foo`. I've provided some wrappers to access the counter outside of `tcolorbox` environments, see the update at the end of my answer please.The `\thetcbcounter` and `\tcbcounter` macros are defined only for the current the environment and are not accessible from outside

Comment: Many thanks. This fills the hole in my ability to use tcbtheorem.

Comment: @RMM: Alright, please consider to accept one of the given answers here then

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Please ask a proper question, not a in row of comments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Would you see my post,

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426592/manipulate-counters-in-tcolorbox-environments related to your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Hupfer, I  have two `tcolorbox` in same docs, are used each having same format and counter name but two custom `tcolorbox` type say one refers to Boys and other to Girls but same design. When referencing using `cref` for both box one after another  I have fatal error as both thetcbcounter is same.  How to rectify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *-variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\providecommand\theoremnumber{}
\newtcbtheorem{Theorembase}{Theorem \theoremnumber}{}{Th}
\newenvironment{Theorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\theoremnumber}{#1}\begin{Theorembase*}}
 {\end{Theorembase*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}{7.9}{}
We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

The second argument for `\begin{theorem}` is the optional title like for normal `tcb` theorems.

[image]

Comment: I see. Essentially you are wresting control of the numbering scheme from tcolorbox and replacing it with \theoremnumber. For a one off, that's fine, but it looks like you're tossing out the ability to use references to the theorem using \ref or similar systems.

Comment: @RMM If you number theorems manually, you don't need automatic cross references.