# Manipulate counters in tcolorbox environments

Tags: counters, tcolorbox

Based on the first answer of this question, [Set number of tcbtheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349313/set-number-of-tcbtheorem/), I tried to deduce some other macros involving tcb counters adapted to my needs, and find this macro, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtotcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \addtocounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}
  }
}
\makeatother
```

which gives what I want. I have tried this macro, similar to the command `\value{counter}`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\valuetcbcounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \value{tcb@cnt@#1}
  }
}
\makeatother
```

But the command `\valuetcbcounter{Theorem}` gives an error. How can I find such a macro ?

I give the .tex file used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providetcbcountername}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    --undefined--%
  }{%
    tcb@cnt@#1%
  }
}

\newcommand{\settcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \setcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}
  }
}

\newcommand{\displaytcbcounter}[1]{% Wrapper for \the...
  \@ifundefined{thetcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \csname thetcb@cnt@#1\endcsname% 
  }%
}
\makeatother
%%%                                 END MANIPULATING COUNTER OF TCOLORBOX   

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtotcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \addtocounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}
  }
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\valuetcbcounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \value{tcb@cnt@#1}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}
\section{My nice section}

\settcbcounter{Theorem}{8}

The counter for theorem is \providetcbcountername{Theorem} and it has the value of \displaytcbcounter{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\addtotcbcounter{Theorem}{2}

After adding 2 to tcbcounter, the macro for displaying the value of \providetcbcountername{Theorem} gives \displaytcbcounter{Theorem}.

%\valuetcbcounter{Theorem} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The definition of `\valuetcbcounter` is correct, but not its usage. You 'must' use  `\number\valuetcbcounter` all the while or place the `\number` primitive in front of `\value` inside the macro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Displaying the counter value without the usual `\the...` macro needs either `\the\c@foo` where `foo` is the counter name or `\number\value{foo}`, so just add `\number` before `\value` in the `\valuetcbcounter` macro.

This way `\valuetcbcounter` can still be used in a `\numexpr` or `\ifnum` way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providetcbcountername}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    --undefined--%
  }{%
    tcb@cnt@#1%
  }
}

\newcommand{\settcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \setcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}%
  }
}

\newcommand{\displaytcbcounter}[1]{% Wrapper for \the...
  \@ifundefined{thetcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \csname thetcb@cnt@#1\endcsname% 
  }%
}
\makeatother
%%%                                 END MANIPULATING COUNTER OF TCOLORBOX   

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtotcbcounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \addtocounter{tcb@cnt@#1}{#2}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\valuetcbcounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@tcb@cnt@#1}{%
    \GenericError{Error}{counter name #1 is no tcb counter }{}{}%
  }{%
    \number\value{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}
\section{My nice section}

\settcbcounter{Theorem}{8}

The counter for theorem is \providetcbcountername{Theorem} and it has the value of \displaytcbcounter{Theorem}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\addtotcbcounter{Theorem}{2}

After adding 2 to tcbcounter, the macro for displaying the value of \providetcbcountername{Theorem} gives \displaytcbcounter{Theorem}.

\valuetcbcounter{Theorem}


Adding a value only for printing, not the value itself
\the\numexpr\valuetcbcounter{Theorem}+2

\ifnum11=\valuetcbcounter{Theorem}%
Hooray!
\else
Nope!
\fi
\end{document}
```